# How to get bash source code blocks to execute .profile / .bashrc

Tags: org-mode, bash, babel

I don't understand how the source code blocks work exactly.

There are some variables, definitions and aliases in my .bashrc that I think I should be able to use in the source code blocks. However, when I run something like the following, the output suggests that my .bashrc is not being run.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC bash :results output
echo $0
echo $VAR_DEFINED_IN_BASHRC
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: bash
:
```

Is this expected behaviour? How do I use the things in my bashrc file in source code blocks?

Comment: from what I understand Emacs will not read your aliases

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find out how your code is executed by checking `ob-shell.el`. As for your particular example, your code is passed to `bash` as stdin, something like the following

```bash
$ echo 'echo $VAR_DEFINED_IN_BASHRC' | bash
```

It will not work, you need the following instead

```bash
$ echo 'echo $VAR_DEFINED_IN_BASHRC' | bash -i
```

So you need to run bash interactively (`-i`) to source your `.bashrc`, your can use `:shebang` argument, then org will create a script (i.e., executable file) and execute it directly via operation system.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :shebang #!/bin/bash -i :results output
echo $VAR_DEFINED_IN_BASHRC
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 42
```

In my `.bashrc`, `VAR_DEFINED_IN_BASHRC` is set to `42`.

Comment: this is an excellent answer. i wonder if there's an easy to also use bash and -i option.